# How do I write this objective-c function in swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have been trying for hours but I cannot figure it out.

```
- (void)magbarDevice:(GTMagBarDevice*)magbarDevice accessoryConnected:(BOOL)isAccessoryConnected
{

}
```

Comment: Why do you need to implement this method in Swift?  It doesn't do anything.  Your Swift code could be improved by simply not calling this method at all, rather than implementing and then calling an empty method.

Comment: This is what i've tried so far func magbarDevice->accessoryConnected(state:BOOL){
    
    }

Comment: There is code inside it, but the code isn't important, I just need to find out how to write the syntax of the method itself

Comment: whats inside the function?  what does the function do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `GTMagBarDevice` is a class:

```
func magbarDevice(magbarDevice: GTMagBarDevice, accessoryConnected isAccessoryConnected: Bool) -> Void {

}
```

Otherwise, if `GTMagBarDevice` is a `struct` or some sort of `typedef`, we might need to specify it as an `inout` parameter.  You didn't include the method body though... I'm just going to assume it's a class.  And if it's not, you can search for `inout` parameters.

And the `-> Void` is entirely optional.  I'd omit it, but I've included it so you can see where to put your return type when you write Swift functions in the future (you shouldn't need to post any more questions like this).

Comment: For some reason I can't ask any more questions on my account, I must have done something wrong? But I have one more question i'll post here just incase you have the answer

Comment: GTMagBarDevice.sharedDevice().delegate = self; I am getting an error with this ... "type view controller does not conform to protocol GTMagBarDeviceDelegate", any ideas?

Comment: Probably your class does not implement it (needs `: GTMagBarDeviceDelegate`right after the class name)